# GCC vs Microsoft : Undefined reference to `_chkstk'?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, mingw

I am using CodeBlocks and MinGW toolchain which is essentially GCC. I was using VStudio but I want to get away from it to do cross platform development. There seems to be some microsoft specific references in some libraries that I am linking, specifically in CXImage SDK (_chkstk). I presume the library was put together using VS. From my searches I have learned that GCC uses _alloca rather than _chkstk. I still want to use CXImage for some stuff I am doing. My question: Is there a way around this problem or am I stuck with ditching libs such as this if I want to use GCC?

Comment: Are you trying to link directly to the same static archive (.lib) you were linking to with Visual Studio?

Comment: I am not sure what was happening, but I started a new project and added the files back in and now it is linking. I did use CB to import the VS file, so I guess it was looking at the wrong libs. So yeah if you want to add an answer about the libs, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you are most likely linking to the wrong `lib` files, since MinGW/gcc compiles things very differently from msvc.  Always try to recompile the libraries from source with the compiler you are using to eventually link them (if you can).