# GOBJECT : unresolved externals symbol ___chkstk_ms

Tags: visual-studio, unresolved-external, gobject

On compiling GOBJECT in Visual Studio, I came across below two
errors:

```
Error   5   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\gtk_compilation\glib\glib-2.46.0\build\win32\vs12\Debug\Win32\bin\gobject-2-vs12.dll gobject
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms referenced in function _ffi_call C:\gtk_compilation\glib\glib-2.46.0\build\win32\vs12\libffi.lib(ffi.o)  gobject
```

I recompiled the libffi using the procedure described [here](http://hostagebrain.blogspot.in/2015/06/building-libffi-on-windows-by-visual.html) but with
extra flags given to `./configure` like below.

```
cflags="-fno-stack-check -fno-stack-protector -mno-stack-arg-probe"
```

which i hope will get rid of the ___chkstk_ms invocations.

After `make` and `make install` of libffi, I renamed the libffi.a to libffi.lib and libffi.dll.a to libffi.dll and copied them to appropriate directories.

Then I  re-build the gobject project in visual studio and I got the same error
which I mentioned in the beginning. :(

Edit:

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554006/gcc-vs-microsoft-undefined-reference-to-chkstk), I guess the problem's root is that I am using two compilers. But i don't see a way to get around it. I tried to compile 
the libffi using Visual Studio Projects available, but hours of efforts
were in vain.

Comment: for the vote-down, please could you mention why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using the MSVC build of Libffi found in the [Github project.](https://github.com/winlibs/libffi)

However, you need to change the line#606 from

```
sizet z = (*p_arg)->size;
```

to

```
unsigned long long  z = (*p_arg)->size;
```

because the typedef is not (for some reason effective here).