# Unresolved external symbol _glfwInit due to 32-bit/64-bit mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors, glfw

How do I link the library in a way that visual studio 2015 can actually see it?

Here's a few screenshot of my folders:
[glfw3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a36fh.png), [glfw3/include/glfw/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS10e.png), [glfw3/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sskjv.png)

I've attempted to link these folders into visual studio, under "vc++ directories => include/library directories as such: [include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDBYq.png), [library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLhF6.png)

also linking the same to my project directly, under linker => input => [additional dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo2SI.png)

to me, that seems like everything is correct (this is how it was in the tutorial i am following, learnopengl.com)

note: I am also doing the same with the GLAD library, which that has a .c file that I put directly into my sources, along with the header files linked the same way as with GLFW.

but despite trying to run this code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    return 0;
}
```

it will always return this error, or similar ones:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: opengl_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Honza\Desktop\C++ programs\lib\glfw3\lib\glfw3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
1>c:\users\honza\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\opengl_test\Debug\opengl_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with how I linked the libraries. I am willing to literally re-install visual studio if I have to, just please give me some possible solutions. I want to start learning opengl but all this jazz with linking libraries is leaving me frustrated and confused.

EDIT: The problem here was that I was using 64-bit GLFW binaries instead of the 32-bit ones, and compiling in 32-bit. I've fixed that, and now I get even more errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: opengl_test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>libglfw3.a(init.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms referenced in function __glfwInputError
1>libglfw3.a(init.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vsnprintf referenced in function __glfwInputError
1>MSVCRTD.lib(vsnprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _vsnprintf
1>libglfw3.a(context.c.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sscanf referenced in function __glfwRefreshContextAttribs
1>MSVCRTD.lib(vsnprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vsnprintf
1>C:\Users\Honza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\opengl_test\Debug\opengl_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'` You sure your target is x64?

Comment: i don't know what that means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You are compiling in 32bits when the glfw library is 64bits. Doesn't work.

Comment: even though I was under the assumption i downloaded the 32-bit glfw binaries, i downloaded them again and this time there's even more errors... https://pastebin.com/4r3qPeCJ

Comment: I think the binaries are still wrong for your compiler.

Comment: I think this is related to the new error but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185622/gobject-unresolved-externals-symbol-chkstk-ms

Comment: @JanProcházka This min you are trying to build your program for the x64 (64-bit) architecture but a part of it (in this case, the library) is x86 (32-bit). This is, most of the time, not going to work. If you're unfamiliar with the difference between x64 and x86, I suggest you read up.

Answer (score 0):

You write that you tried to link "these folders", while in fact, you need 2 separate things in order to use a function from a static library.

1. Use the proper header file so compilation succeeds. From the error you quoted, compilation went well. The program knows there is an external function named _glfwInit.
2. Link to the specific library (.lib file). Looks like you placed a path of a folder and not the full path of the .lib file.

Under Linker => input => additional dependencies, place the full path of the gfw3.lib file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while following learnopengl.com, The issue is that you need to **rebuild** glfw library with **cmake** again,
but this time when you choose visual studio 2015 or whatever for your generator for this project, you must also choose: **OPTIONAL PLATFORM FOR GENERATOR -> x64** 
you can make sure that every thing is OK when you **build glfw** inside **Visual Studio** and the platform that appears is **x64**